# Assigning multiple indices at once from one list

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

I have five user variables with different names. I'd like them to end up in an array, and am wondering if I can do the assignment to multiple array indices in a single line. Currently, if I do this

```
var users = {user5k, user10k, user15k, user20k, user25k};
```

I can't index it later (says `users[0]` is undefined). So I want the indices built in to the assignment. Something along these lines:

```
var users = {};
users[0:4] = {user5k, user10k, user15k, user20k, user25k};
```

This doesn't seem possible in JavaScript, meaning I have to do this:

```
var users = {};
users[0] = user5k;
users[1] = user10;
// ... et cetera
```

Is there a way to accomplish the first solution?

Comment: `{}` is for objects, `[]` is for arrays.

Comment: Yes, you are defining an `object` when you use `{}`. For an array which you can index, use `[]`.

Comment: In case it's not clear, you need `var users = [user5k, user10k, user15k, user20k, user25k];`

Comment: I'd go back to your JS tutorial/intro and carefully re-read the part about basic data types, including objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `{}` you're creating an object, not an array. Use `[]` for arrays.

```
var users = [user5k, user10k, user15k, user20k, user25k];
```

If you want to replace part of an array that already exists, you can use `Array.prototype.splice()`

```
var users = [];
users.splice(0, 4, [user5k, user10k, user15k, user20k, user25k]);
```